# Configuring a GigabitEthernet interface on a Cisco router

Tags: networking, router, gigabit-ethernet

I'm trying to set the ip address of a GigabitEthernet interface on a Cisco MWR 2941 router. I have tried the following:

```
config t
interface gigabitethernet0/2
ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
```

However, I got the error:

```
IP address may not be configured on L2 links.
```

How do I configure the port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked the [Product Spec](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps9395/data_sheet_c78-419853.html) for this router. In the list of features I saw this

```
Built-in Layer 2 Gigabit Ethernet switch supporting line-rate traffic
```

So the gigabit ports on your router are actually part of a built in switch, layer two devices cannot be configured with an IP address.

What you can do however. Is create a vlan and add those ports to the vlan. The vlan is then given an IP address which I think will help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just try no switchport on the interface and that should do the trick. Some old version dont allow providing IP address on the interfaces directly, so this command should work for your case.

Packet Viewer

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that?